# Synthetic steps for the interconversion between aldehydes and ketones

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, carbonyl-compounds

I am learning about carbonyl chemistry at the moment. So far, we have been able to make aldehydes and ketones from alcohols (via oxidizing agents). I can't help but wonder if there is possibly any way to make aldehydes from ketones or vice-versa through a series of synthetic steps. I would appreciate it if the synthetic steps are in the level of an undergraduate organic chemistry course.

**Question: Synthetic steps for the interconversion between aldehydes and ketones?**

Comment: You could reduce an aldehyde to a primary alcohol, dehydrate the alcohol to an alkene, hydrate it again with the hydroxyl on the other side (secondary alcohol), and then oxidize to get the ketone.

Comment: @KarstenTheis yes, I was able to figure this out with the given answers, but I am still having trouble going in the reverse direction. Ketones to aldehydes.

Comment: Check out hydroboration vs. oxymercuration, e.g. by looking at this [cheat sheet](http://leah4sci.com/alkene-reactions-overview-cheat-sheet-organic-chemistry/). Once you have the hydroxyl group on the carbon where you want it, you just have to make sure your oxidation does not go all the way to a carboxylic acid.

Comment: @JamesBond For converting Ketones to aldehydes, what you can do is to perform a **Bayer-Villiger Oxidation**  on the ketone to get an ester. The ester what you got can now be reduced with **DIBAL-H** (Diisobutylaluminium hydride) to get an aldehyde and the other part will leave as alcohol which you can again oxidise using PCC.

Comment: @SoumikDas Thanks! Makes perfect sense since I already know about the ester to aldehyde via DIBAL-H. The Bayer-Villiger Oxidation was the key to getting to the ester. Thanks a lot. If you want you can post your answer so I can accept it, I like this more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily convert aldehydes to ketones and vice-versa by using simple organic synthetic steps which are very much well known.

**Converting aldehydes to ketones**

For converting aldehydes to ketones there are numerous pathways. Here I am mentioning the simplest two ways, one of which is by using Grignard reagent and other by using thioacetal intermediates.

You can react aldehydes with Grignard reagents ($\ce{R^2 -MgBr}$) and perform acidic workup to generate secondary alcohols. Then you can oxidise the alcohol to get a ketone by commonly used oxidising agents like PCC (pyridinium chlorochromate).

The other way is to react the aldehyde with a propane-1,3-dithiol to generate a cyclic thioacetal . Now, interestingly, the proton attached to the carbon now can be removed by strong base like n-Butyllithium, and generate  Carbanion which can perform a $S_N2 $ reaction with an alkyl halide to generate cyclic thioketal. After that the thioketal can be hydrolysed using $\ce{HgCl2/CdCO3/H2O}$  to generate your desired ketone.

[image]

**Converting ketones to aldehydes**

The easiest step for this conversion is to perform a Bayer-Villiger Oxidation reaction on the ketone to get an ester. Then that ester can be reduced by Diisobutylaluminium Hydride (DIBAL-H) and an aqueous workup will generate desired aldehyde (along with an alcohol). (If you wish you can further oxidise that alcohol also in case you want aldehyde of that part).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**There are two distinct ways to convert aldehydes into ketones and vice versa**

An aldehyde is a carbonyl group on a primary carbon while a ketone is a carbonyl group on a secondary carbon. To interconvert the two, you can either keep the functional group on a given carbon and make/break carbon-carbon bonds. Or you can move the functional group along the existing carbon backbone without breaking carbon-carbon bonds.

**Moving the carbonyl functional group**

Enzymatic conversion from aldehyde to ketone and back is common in the biochemistry of carbohydrates. In glycolysis, for example, phosphorylated dihydroxyacetone is converted to glyceraldehyde. Sugars have a hydroxyl group alpha to the carbonyl group. In the enzymatic reaction, isomerization proceeds via an enediol intermediate ([source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Isomerase.gif)):

[image]

A similar acid/base mechanism is used in the interconversion of glucose to fructose. This is a commercially relevant reaction for making high fructose corn syrup.

**Turn a primary carbon into a secondary carbon and vice versa**

See Soumik Das' answer.